# clear apt-get list

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I am building an image for an embedded Linux based on Debian. I did use `apt-get update` before on the device that I want to use as a base for that image, so the lists under `/var/lib/apt/lists` are quite large (almost 100 MB in size).

I want to keep `apt-get` functionality (so I don't want to remove apt repositories) but I want to free the space used up in these lists (the lists almost double the size of the image).

Does anyone know how to do that? Can I just delete the files under `/var/lib/apt/lists`?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can just use:

```bash
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

This will remove the package lists. No repositories will be deleted, they are configured in the config file in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. All that can happen is that tools like `apt-cache` cannot get package information unless you updated the package lists. Also `apt-get install` will fail with `E: Unable to locate package <package>`, because no information is available about the package.

Then just run:

```bash
apt-get update
```

to rewrite those lists and the command will work again.

Anyway, it's recommended to run `apt-get update` before installing anything.

Comment: Obviously the directory may not be empty, kindly add -rf after the rm to look like this ```rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*```

Answer (score 8):

The lists are the knowledge of what's available, so if you delete them, you won't be able to install anything - that's exactly equivalent to removing the repositories from your sources list (which you say you don't want to do).

One option is that you could compress the lists, and remember to uncompress them before you next `update`.

What I often do (particularly when I want to experiment with extra sources) is to create a directory `/etc/apt/sources.available` and add entries for distributions.  I can then easily enable any subset by creating symlinks from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and disable by removing those symlinks.

With empty sources list, you could `apt-get update` - that should clear your `/var/lib/apt/lists`.  Then link appropriate sources back into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, but don't `update` until such time as you actually intend to use them.